# PHP pgsql query to populate select List is resulting in empty option tags

Tags: php, postgresql

I am attempting to populate an html select menu in php with a database query. There are no errors on inspection or in the logs and the select statement tests ok in pgadmin. The resulting source code displays empty `<option>`s.

The source code looks like this on inspect:

```
<option></option> ==$0
```

It is also returning more than 25,000

PG Connection made...

```
        $sql = "SELECT tech_support2.site_id FROM fpscdb001_ws_001.tech_support2";
        $rs = pg_query($conn, $sql);

               if (pg_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
                 $menu .= "<option value=".$row['ProbType'].">" . $row['ProbType']. "</option>";
   }
}

 echo $menu;
pg_close($conn);
```

Comment: Have you checked if you enter your `if`? Or simply `var_dump(pg_num_rows($rs))`?

Comment: Could you explain how to check if it is entering the if?

Comment: `var_dump(pg_num_rows($rs))`

Comment: Thank you for your replies... I am a cut an paste coder with only half of an idea of what to expect when a given script is ran. So i apologize for seeming clueless... I pasted var_dump function above the if and I got the exact same result.

Comment: You select `site_id` field from table. Then why do you use `ProbType`?

Comment: Good question u_mulder... I missed it, now it works.